# How to change the values of cv2.boundingRect

Tags: python, opencv

is there a way to change the values of cv2.boundingRect

[image]

I want to adjust so I can get the accurate cv2.drawContours
[image]

```
import cv2

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread("5.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find bounding box

x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(thresh)
cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
cv2.putText(image, "w={},h={}".format(w,h), (x,y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("image", image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: how do you actually want to adjust it?

Comment: this method cv2.rectangle without using numpy slicing.

Comment: Just modify x,y,w,h after cv2.boundingRect() and before cv2.rectangle(). If you just want to make the right side of the green rectangle further to the right, then just increase w. Is that not obvious or do I misunderstand what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to do. But I see two different ways to approach this in Python/OpenCV.

1) Just increase w

```
import cv2

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread("5.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find bounding box    
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(thresh)
w = w + 9
cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
cv2.putText(image, "w={},h={}".format(w,h), (x,y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("image", image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image]

2) Dilate your thresholded image

```
import cv2

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread("5.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# apply morphology dilate
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (9,9))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# Find bounding box   
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(thresh)
cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)
cv2.putText(image, "w={},h={}".format(w,h), (x,y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("image", image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image]

Comment: This solved my problem, Thanks